# Free and standalone application for projects time-tracking

Tags: offline, project-management, time-management, tracking

My software development team is looking for a very simple time-tracking/timesheet app, with the following requirements:

- Free
- Possibility to define multiple projects
- Basic, clean calendar interface
- **Standalone, meaning not cloud-based, no login, just install it on your machine and your data stays there**

Machines have Windows 7/10. About the price, since we are evaluating time-tracking processes we are looking for something free, for now. I've already saved some paid applications for the future.

There are a lot of beautiful apps around, but they are web-based or standalone with online login and we don't want to rely on a remote infrastructure. We will consider them in a near future after this "offline test" phase.

I've found only one app that perfectly fits my needs: [Spinso TimeTracker Lite](http://www.spinso.com/time_tracker/Lite/Index.htm). The problem? It is *really* unstable... lots of application errors and so on. Anything else around?

Comment: Short question: What engine does your machine run on? And what is your price limit if it comes to paid software?

Comment: Machines have Windows 7/10, what other kinds of "engines" are you referring to? If talking about locale web servers then no, there aren't.
About the price, since we are evaluating time-tracking processes we are looking for something free, for now. I've already saved some paid applications for the future.

Comment: Exactly that, Alessandro – so thanks for the update! I was so free as to integrate that with your question to make it easier to spot. Good luck then!

Comment: Have you tried [Rachota](http://rachota.sourceforge.net/en/index.html)? It is not web based but runs from USB drive, though. But it is free and lets you define multiple projects.

Answer (score 2):

What about [ActivityWatch](https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch)? It does not have a calender yet, but I use it to track different activities quite efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a time-tracking Windows desktop program called Timesheet Sidekick.  I think the free trial version meets your requirements.  The trial version has some limitations, but you can use it as long as you like, and it might meet your needs as-is.  (Though I expect that in the 3 years since you asked this, you have since found another solution!)

There is a 15-minute overview video on the web site:

http://www.timesheetsidekick.com/